# Extended WPF toolkit - Progress Indicator, binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpftoolkit, busyindicator

Im trying to bind an **ObservableCollection** of

```
public class ProgressInfo : BindableBase, IProgress<Tuple<string, int>>
{
    public ProgressInfo()
    {
        Message = "start";
        ProgressBarValue = 50;
    }

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => Message); }
    }

    private int _progressBarValue;
    public int ProgressBarValue
    {
        get { return _progressBarValue; }
        set { _progressBarValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => ProgressBarValue); }
    }

    public void Report(Tuple<string, int> value)
    {
        this.Message = value.Item1;
        this.ProgressBarValue = value.Item2;
    }

}
```

to WPF Toolkit BusyIndicator with custom content

```
  <xctk:BusyIndicator DisplayAfter="0" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"  >
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Static lang:Resources.TRWAIMPORT}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding  ProgressInfos, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgressInfo.Message, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay }"/>
                    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=ProgressInfo.ProgressBarValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="15"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
```

Also I'm passing objects from the **ObervableCollection** to my **Tasks** so they change their properties through the Report method.

But for some reason the **BusyIndicator** is never updated with new values and the **ObservableCollection** seems to always be empty (**ItemsControl** doesn't produce any items)

What am I doing wrong ? This approach worked on any other control but the **BusyIndicator** seems it doesn't get it right

Comment: I'm not familiar with WPF Toolkit, but:

Why ONE BusyIndicator needs COLLECTION (ItemsSource) of items?
I would expect here binding to ONE ProgressInfo object.

Do you see initial values of your ProgressInfo object and no actualizing or you didn't get anything?

Comment: Well the busyIndicator itself only needs  the IsBusy property. I changed its internal template so it contains ItemsControl, which needs a collection of objects and generates its data template for every object in its collection. Anyway I tried changing it and binding only one ProgressInfo object to a different BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate. it still doesn't bind. Even if I populate the object with initial values, it still doesn't show anything.

Comment: @SebOlens hi. can you share working code?

Comment: @user1088259 Hi. I wish I could but it was 2 years ago and the code is long gone :)